# Is it possible for two references to the same object to be !==?

Tags: javascript, reference, comparison

I got stuck on the [Mozilla shim for Object.is()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is).  I'm vaguely familiar with the difference between == and ===, but is there a typo in this code?  If not, how and why would v1 ever !== v1?

```
if (!Object.is) {
  Object.is = function(v1, v2) {
    if (v1 === 0 && v2 === 0) {
      return 1 / v1 === 1 / v2;
    }
    if (v1 !== v1) {
      return v2 !== v2;
    }
    return v1 === v2;
  };
}
```

Comment: 1) JavaScript does *not* have "references" in that Java/C# meaning; 2) `x == x` and `x === x` are true for *any* `x` except for NaN.

Comment: Only if that is not an object, but the `NaN` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will happen when v1 is NaN.

The reason it performs the same check with v2:

```
    if (v1 !== v1) {
      return v2 !== v2;
    }
```

is because, according to the same documentation, the function needs to return true when comparing two values of NaN, and (obviously) false when comparing it with any other value. One of the only reliable ways to check if a value is NaN (i.e. the value NaN, not the concept "is not a number") is to compare it with itself for inequality.

Comment: "The only way to check if a value is NaN is to compare it with itself for inequality" What about isNaN().

Comment: @TGH +1 for clarity. :)

Comment: Thanks! That's an odd little thing, a bit quirky IMHO.  But, as usual, I just didn't read carefully enough.

Comment: @Nolo— *isNaN* returns true for any non–number value (e.g. `isNaN('foo') === true`), it doesn't just test for the *NaN* value.

Comment: There are other ways to test for *NaN*, e.g. `typeof x == 'number' && isNaN(x)`, but `x !== x` is less to type. :-)

Comment: @RobG: Can you tell how rusty my JS knowledge is yet? ;)